# Getting product object inside defaultinvoice.php file for getting custom attribute values

Tags: magento2, product, pdf, override-model, overriding

I will tell what i have done till now.

I have made a custom module to override the

> Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice

file and its working fine.

I am able to get sku, name, price in the invoice pdf in any location. Now i am trying to get the product object inside it to get custom attribute values.

Most of the tutorials i found is advised to use objectmanager that i am not interested in looking into. Rather i need to include those via factory or repository.

my question is how we can get product object inside model file(for example defaultinvoice.php file).

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

**ProductRepository dependency injection Method:**
**Need to rewrite this file (DefaultInvoice.php) in app/code..**

```
E:\kjn\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice.php
```

Add bellow code before `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource` $resource = null,

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
```

and after $this->string = $string; add

```
$this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
```

Before the function public function draw() put

```
 public function getProductById($id)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
}
```

Then you can call the function getProductById by passing the product id. passing SKU is another method.

Load the product id from $item

```
$ProductId = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductId();
```

then calling product collection function

```
$product = $this->getProductById($ProductId);
```

By using the $product collection. i have get the product custom attribute value

```
 $SizeUnit = '';
            if (strtolower($option['label']) == strtolower($product->getLengthName()))
            {
                $SizeUnit = ' ' . $product->getResource()->getAttribute('size_units')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            }
```